# WooCommerce custom product dimensions

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a variable product with the following size parameters:

Length
Width
Height
Weight
Diameter

In the product edit page I have Length, Width, Height, Weight

How do I go about adding a Diameter?

On the front end I would like to call it like this

```
<?php echo $product->get_diameter() . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ); ?>
```